# ActiveRecord::Base Extension not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I try to use the code below to extend active record to have my order class a bit cleaner. It is however not working.

```
class ActiveRecord::Base   
  def self.has_statuses(*status_names)
    validates :status, 
              :presence => true, 
              :inclusion => { :in => status_names} 

    status_names.each do |status_name|
      scope "all_#{status_name}", where(:status => status_name)
    end

    status_names.each do |status_name|
      define_method "#{status_name}?" do
         status == status_name
      end
    end  
  end
end
```

In environment.rb I require the above extension with

```
require "#{Rails.root}/lib/active_record_extensions.rb"
```

If I on the other hand creates an abstract base class OrderBase and let's my order class inherit from that instead it is working as anticipated. What do I need to do to make my monkey patch "take"?

**EDIT:** forgot to mention I get a message saying method missing for has_statuses.

**EDIT2:** The above code works in console (rails c) but it does not work in test

**EDIT3:** I changed environment/test.rb to config.cache_classes = false and that seems to do the trick. Obviously have a lot to learn :)

Comment: This actually works for me, how are you using this method?

Comment: I am trying to use it in my Order class like: has_statuses :created, :in_progress, :shipped etc to keep the class clean.

Comment: @seeingidog err now it is working for me as well and I have no idea what is different.... I obviously have done something but don't know what. Post an answer saying it should be working and I'll mark that as the answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added the require to the top of my order class

```
require "#{Rails.root}/lib/active_record_extensions.rb"
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
```

Answer (score 0):

Where do you store that extension code?  I've found that extensions to important Rails classes don't work from the "config/initializers/" directory (where I'd prefer to keep them, for tidiness's sake), but do work if I tack the extension code on at the end of "config/environment.rb" (which I don't like at all, 'cause it gets messy really fast).  I've never figured out why.

I'm on Rails 2.3.8, so if you're on Rails 3, this might no longer apply...

**EDIT:**

I forgot the other trick it took to get an `ActiveRecord::Base` extension working - the methods (class methods, at least - I haven't done it with an instance method) have to be declared in the *metaclass* (I think that's what it's called...).  Here's my working `ActiveRecord::Base` extension:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.class_eval do
    class << self
        def find_with_benchmark(*args)
            bg = Time.now
            ret = find_without_benchmark(*args)
            MyLogger.ar_time += Time.now - bg
            MyLogger.ar_count += 1
            return ret
        end

        alias_method_chain :find, :benchmark
    end
end
```

Comment: thanks, I also tried to include the code at the end of environment.rb but get the same result. Method missing :(

Comment: @mhenrixon Oho!  Wait!  I forgot something else I had to do to get my `ActiveRecord::Base` extension working!  I'll tack it on to my answer - one minute...

Comment: trying your way of doing this I run in to a problem where it complains about an unexpected \n expected [ or . so I guess there has been some changes to how this works.